# Change displayed date onbuttonclick of buttons ranging from Sunday to Saturday

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, datetime

I have the following button panel in my solution that has the buttons Sunday, Monday, Tuesday... Saturday.

The buttons are already set up to only display information via a gridview on the current week using an sql statement.

What I want to do is populate a textbox with the day of the week that is selected at the top.

So, if it's Sunday, I want Monday to display tomorrows date, Thursday to display the date 4 days from now, etc., and if it's Saturday, the dates would have to subtract unless Saturday was selected.

Is there an existing article that shows how to do this, or can anyone help me with this?

I was thinking about doing a ton of if statements, but not sure it's the best way, and not quite sure about how I'd go about programming that.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you plese post the code you currently have, will be esy to go from there

Comment: what code do you have thus far...?? also look at the AddDays() method within the datetime quick hint.. if you want to add 2 days it's addDays(2) if you want to subtract days its addDays(-2) DateTime.Now.AddDays(2) DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2) would be the syntax you will have to code the logic to fix your scenario

Answer (score 0):

When they select the day of week button are you doing a postback?  You could create a DateTime variable instance and then do DateTime.AddDays(1), etc.

For example your server could would be:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2011, 12, 21);
dt.AddDays(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing any code it's kinda hard to ensure that I fully understand what your asking.

If the buttons can populate a field that represents sunday for the current week, then you can set the text on your buttons based on that date and the AddDays function.

So I'm assuming (Today is Wednesday December 21, 2011)

you would have 7 buttons.  You want the buttons to read something like

2011-12-18 | 2011-12-19 | 2011-12-20 | TODAY | 2011-12-22 | 2011-12-23 | 2011-12-24 (assuming your week starts on Sunday).

So if we click Wednesday (today) you calculate what Sunday is, and then you can do something along the lines of

```
ButtonMonday = sundayDate.AddDays(1).ToString();
ButtonTuesday = sundayDate.AddDays(2).ToString();
```

You'd need to add a little bit of logic to check to see if the Button is the Current Date and display Today instead, but that's the gist of it.

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime dateTimeCurrent = new DateTime.Now();
dateTimeCurrent = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1); ect... you get the picture
```